# Map rendering issues when navigate the page in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

[image: Click here for more]

In android device its working fine but issue for only for ios device.

When I am open the newpage1 page from “Map” tab and return back from newpage1 page then it shows half of the map screen.

```
Version:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.1, ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, (and 24 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 2.0.0
NodeJS : v10.1.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.1.0/bin/node)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255

<engine name=“android” spec=“7.1.1” />
<engine name=“ios” spec=“4.5.5” />

“@angular/core”: “5.2.10”,
“@ionic-native/google-maps”: “^4.14.0”,

“cordova-plugin-googlemaps”: “^2.4.4”,
“cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk”: “https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk/tarball/2.7.0”,
```

Comment: Are you using your newpage1  as modal or as page?

Comment: I used page this.navCtrl.push(NotificationlistPage);

Comment: Can you share your html and sass code only then I can explain you the issue.

Comment: <ion-content>
  <div class="map-class" id="map_canvas"></div>
</ion-content>

Comment: .map-class {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }